# How to change IF Statement to Select....Case

Tags: vb.net

I've got the following that has got multiple values of a particular variable and I don't want to stack up to a lot of `IF ELSE` statements to handle them, so I'd be grateful if some one could very kindly modify the code by using the `SELECT CASE` statement.

Also, I'd like `dgMarksEntry.Item(7, i).Value` and  `dgMarksEntry.Item(8, i).Value` to handle `RANK` and `COUNT` the number of items entered respectively.

```
 For i = 0 To 100
        dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value = Val(dgMarksEntry.Item(3, i).Value) + Val(dgMarksEntry.Item(2, i).Value)

        If dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value >= 80 Then
            dgMarksEntry.Item(5, i).Value = "A1"
            dgMarksEntry.Item(6, i).Value = "Excellent"
        ElseIf dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value >= 75 Then
            dgMarksEntry.Item(5, i).Value = "B2"
            dgMarksEntry.Item(6, i).Value = "Very good"
        ElseIf dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value >= 70 Then
            dgMarksEntry.Item(5, i).Value = "B3"
            dgMarksEntry.Item(6, i).Value = "Good"
        ElseIf dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value >= 65 Then
            dgMarksEntry.Item(5, i).Value = "C4"
            dgMarksEntry.Item(6, i).Value = "Credit"
        ElseIf dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value >= 60 Then
            dgMarksEntry.Item(5, i).Value = "C5"
            dgMarksEntry.Item(6, i).Value = "Credit"
        ElseIf dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value >= 55 Then
            dgMarksEntry.Item(5, i).Value = "C6"
            dgMarksEntry.Item(6, i).Value = "Credit"
        ElseIf dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value >= 50 Then
            dgMarksEntry.Item(5, i).Value = "D7"
            dgMarksEntry.Item(6, i).Value = "Pass"
        ElseIf dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value >= 40 Then
            dgMarksEntry.Item(5, i).Value = "E8"
            dgMarksEntry.Item(6, i).Value = "Weak pass"
        ElseIf dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value <= 39 Then
            dgMarksEntry.Item(5, i).Value = "F9"
            dgMarksEntry.Item(6, i).Value = "Fail"
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You want *us* to code for *you*??!

Comment: please show your SQL... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose a completely different approach. First, declare a class, which can contain rating information:

```
Public Class CreditRating
    Private m_Limit As Integer
    Public Property Limit() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Limit
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_Limit = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Rating As String
    Public Property Rating() As String
        Get
            Return m_Rating
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Rating = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Appreciation As String
    Public Property Appreciation() As String
        Get
            Return m_Appreciation
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Appreciation = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then change your logic to:

```
Dim ratings As New List(Of CreditRating)

ratings.Add(New CreditRating With {.Limit = 80, .Rating = "A1", .Appreciation = "Excellent"})
ratings.Add(New CreditRating With {.Limit = 75, .Rating = "B2", .Appreciation = "Very good"})
ratings.Add(New CreditRating With {.Limit = 70, .Rating = "B3", .Appreciation = "Good"})
ratings.Add(New CreditRating With {.Limit = 65, .Rating = "C4", .Appreciation = "Credit"})
ratings.Add(New CreditRating With {.Limit = 60, .Rating = "C5", .Appreciation = "Credit"})
ratings.Add(New CreditRating With {.Limit = 55, .Rating = "C6", .Appreciation = "Credit"})
ratings.Add(New CreditRating With {.Limit = 50, .Rating = "D7", .Appreciation = "Pass"})
ratings.Add(New CreditRating With {.Limit = 40, .Rating = "E8", .Appreciation = "Weak pass"})
ratings.Add(New CreditRating With {.Limit = 0, .Rating = "F9", .Appreciation = "Fail"})

For i As Integer = 0 To 100
    Dim value As Double = Conversion.Val(dgMarksEntry(3, i).Value) + Conversion.Val(dgMarksEntry(2, i).Value)
    dgMarksEntry(4, i).Value = value
    For Each rating As CreditRating In ratings
        If value >= rating.Limit Then
            dgMarksEntry(5, i).Value = rating.Rating
            dgMarksEntry(6, i).Value = rating.Appreciation
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

With this approach, you could also read the rating information from a file or database. This makes it easier to change the limits. It is also less error prone, since the logic is programmed only once and is the same for all the limits.

Comment: Thanks so much. I perfectly understand your code. It works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to do it is on this page, including some examples to get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx

Comment: I've checked the link but I still could get it very well. Please just try to change my IF ELSE statement to SELECT CASE for me. Just work out some example for me.

Comment: @Akaglo: Instead of `If dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value >= 80 Then`, did you try writing `Case dgMarksEntry.Item(4, i).Value Is >= 80` ? And so on...